# async await performance hits

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

For an express Controller method as below, being nested with a few async awaits, will it have any performance hits?

All the logic currently sits in the controller method for simplicity sake. But I am well aware that I can refactor these out.

I have used async on some of the promise resolutions `then`. And at the top level. I am not sure if this will significantly degrade performance or if its an arguable practice?

```
  async registerUser(req, res, next) {
    const trx = await transaction.start(this.User.knex());
    let userData = {};
    AuthService.hashPassword(req.body.password)
      .then(password => {
        userData = {
          first_name: req.body.firstName,
          last_name: req.body.lastName,
          email: req.body.email,
          password: password,
          tenant_id: req.body.tenantId
        };

        return userData;
      }).then(async userData => {
        return this.User
          .query()
          .insert(userData);
      })
      .then(async user =>  {
        let token = await AuthService.signPayload(user);
        return {
          token,
          user
        };
      })
      .then(async payload => {
        await trx.commit();
        console.log(payload);
        res.status(201);
        res.jsonp({
          success: true,
          data: {
            user: payload.user,
            token: payload.token
          }
        });
      }).catch(async e => {
        await trx.rollback();
        console.log(e);
        res.status(400);
        res.jsonp({
          success: false,
          errors: true,
          data: {
            message: 'Registration failed',
            user: userData
          }
        })
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I've changed your code to look more synchronic, so you can see all pros and cons.

About performance hits, it is best solution to use `async/await` in your code.

About this:

> can refactor these out.

```js
const registerUser = (req, res, next) => {
  const trx = await transaction.start(this.User.knex());
  let password;

  try {
    password = await AuthService.hashPassword(req.body.password);
  } catch (e) {
    // Some error. You can throw it or message user or do whatever you want.
    console.error("Error with auth", e.message);
    return await errorTransaction(res, trx);
  }

  let userData = {
    first_name: req.body.firstName,
    last_name: req.body.lastName,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: password,
    tenant_id: req.body.tenantId
  };

  try {
    await this.User.query().insert(userData);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("Error during insert", e.message);
    return;
  }

  let token = await AuthService.signPayload(user);
  let tokenUserData = {
    token,
    user
  };

  try {
    await trx.commit();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("Error in commit.", e.message);
    return await errorTransaction(res, trx, userData);
  }
  res.status(201);
  res.jsonp({
    success: true,
    data: {
      user: payload.user,
      token: payload.token
    }
  });
}

const errorTransaction = async (res, trx, userData={}) => {
  await trx.rollback();

  res.status(400);
  res.jsonp({
   success: false,
   errors: true,
   data: {
     message: 'Registration failed',
     user: userData
   }
  });
}
```

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, but in the effort you're leaving out some important stuff, like not rolling back the transaction in case of exceptions, or sending back a response at all times.

Comment: @robertklep, please scroll down my code snippet, there is try...catch for transaction. And about response, I've just used authors code.

Comment: You're only checking for exceptions on `trx.commit()`, but the transaction is started right at the top and for every exception that can occur, it's the intention of the original code to roll back the transaction before returning. Also, the original code has a top-level `catch` block that will handle all exceptions, roll back the transaction _and_ send back a response. That's missing from your code (you're calling `console.log()` and returning, leaving both the transaction and the request dangling).

Comment: @robertklep oh, I see. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Grynets is there a downside of wrapping all of these in a single try/catch block?

Comment: @GayanHewa as stated in MDN documentation about try catch https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch try block will execute anyway, but if error occurred, only than catch block will be executed. So there is literally no difference, between code without try...catch and with try..catch if your code produce no errors.